# Using Process to display an external program inside winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am trying to embed part of an external program (part of its window) inside a existing WinForm that I am developing.

Following examples online, I came out with the following. I assume that the process name is unique , singular and that it is already open, in the example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] myProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("the_external_program_i_want");
    Process p = myProc[0];
    IntPtr appWin = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);
    SetWindowLong(appWin, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
    MoveWindow(appWin, panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
}
```

My issue is that after i close my WinForm, I realised that this external program will trigger a pop-up box saying that "program_name has stopped working".

My question is that is there additional functions that I will neeed to call, to close the external program correctly, within the WinForm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make the `p` variable accesible to the whole class.
Then add a event listener to the FormClosing event:

```
this.FormClosing += Window_FormClosing;

void Window_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe it is so simple.